# NSoperation reverse dependencies

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

In one of my apps i have a NSOperationQueue and some subclass of NSOperations.
I've added some dependencies so, the operation A not start until operation B finish.

I need to cancel the operation A if the operation B fails, but from inside the operation B i don't have any list of operation who dependes on the current operation.

I will try to add some weak properties on my subclass, like

`@property (nonatomic, weak) NSArray *dependsOnMe;`

but i'm afraid to generate some strange loop.

thanks

Comment: The weak NSArray property will not do what you want: it will weakly reference the array, not its elements. The array will probably get deallocated as soon as you lose other references to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres a bit of missing info here. Like when you construct B , do you also construct A?

Is there a need to do this? Why not construct A on the successful completion of B?

You could use use a delegate protocol if its a one to one dependancy from B to A

```
@protocol DependantOperationCompletion <NSObject>

-(void)operationDidFail;

@end

@interface BOperation

@property (weak) id<DependantOperationCompletion> delegate;

@end
```

and

```
@interface AOperation:NSOperation <DependantOperationCompletion> 

...

@end
```

then when you construct the operations set up A as a delegate of B

`bOpInstance.delegate = aOpInstance;`

Alternatively use the "Shout out the window" approach and post a notification if B fails. A listens for the notification.

within B...

```
-(void)handleFailure
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:BTypeOpDidFailNotification object:self userInfo:someInfoOrNil]

}
```

within A...

```
-(void)setupWithBOp:(BOperation *)binstance
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ohNoBHazFailed:) name:BTypeOpDidFailNotification object:binstance];

}
```

Remember to remove A as observer on `dealloc`

Comment: to answer to your question, I prefer create all operation in the same time for obtain a more readable code.
Actually the chain of operations contains four operations!

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm way late in the discussion, here's what I've written to help me get reverse dependencies for an NSOperation. If you know the queue used, then you can use this extension:

```
extension NSOperationQueue {
    func reverseDependenciesForOperation(op: NSOperation) -> [NSOperation] {
        return operations.filter { $0.dependencies.contains(op) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 I've added some dependencies so, the operation A not start until operation B finish.
```

And:

```
I need to cancel the operation A if the operation B fails
```

You see where this is going?

What would make sense, would be from `B` to cancel `B` if `B` fails. But again, `A` will only start when `B` finishes.

---

From [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues):

> Dependency: you can make an operation dependent on other operations.
>   Any operation can be dependent on any number of operations. When you
>   make operation A dependent on operation B, even though you call
>   “start” on operation A, it will not start unless operation B
>   isFinished is true. For example:

```
MyDownloadOperation *downloadOp = [[MyDownloadOperation alloc] init]; // MyDownloadOperation is a subclass of NSOperation
MyFilterOperation *filterOp = [[MyFilterOperation alloc] init]; // MyFilterOperation  is a subclass of NSOperation

[filterOp addDependency:downloadOp];
```

Comment: sorry, i don't see the point. A depends on B but if B fails A must be cancelled. With the standard implementation even if B fail A will be executed.

Comment: Show me how you are doing `A depends on B`.

Comment: in your example filterOb is dependent of downloadOp and this is ok. The problem is that even if the downloadOp fails the filterOb will be executed. I need a way to achieve the list of "dependent" operation from downloadOp, so i can call "cancel" on all this operations.
I solved the problem with a "failureBlock" called on my viewcontroller, so i can cancel all others operations.

Comment: That's not true. If the downloadOp fails the filter won't be executed.  That's the whole point of using a dependency.

Comment: Hum...NSOperation doesn't have a "return value" so "success" or "fail" are internal states (success if download is ok, fail if download fails). How can filterOb can understand that downloadOp fails?

Comment: I don't know the internals of `NSOperation`, but I guess it uses KVO to signal the dependent part that it failed. You should rely on this to do what you want.

Comment: From the doc: The dependencies supported by NSOperation **make no distinction about whether a dependent operation finished successfully or unsuccessfully**. (In other words, canceling an operation similarly marks it as finished.) It is up to you to determine whether an operation with dependencies should proceed in cases where its dependent operations were cancelled or did not complete their task successfully.
[link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSOperation)